# MATLAB: Making a matrix with shifted Rows

Tags: matlab

All,

Say I want to make a matrix such as:

```
[2 1 0 0 0]
[1 2 1 0 0]
[0 1 2 1 0]
[0 0 1 2 1]
[0 0 0 1 2]
```

I know that there is a way to do this in matlab by feeding it:

```
"command"([1 2 1 0 0])
```

But I don't remember what the command is, and google is not helpful. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
toeplitz([2 1 0 0 0])
```

is probably what you are looking for.